# Обнуление указателя на структуру через функцию

Tags: c++

И так, у меня есть две функции, одна выделяет память под структуру, другая освобождает. Ну а так как проблемы с двойным освобождением памяти хочется избежать, то я решил проверять на 'нулёвость' указатель и обнулять его после освобождения.

Меньше слов, больше кода:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ((type *)((char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member)))

using Tint  = int64_t;
using Tuint = uint64_t;
using Pint  = Tint *;

struct Numx
{
    Tuint
        alen;
    Tint
        len;
    bool
        sgn;
    Tint
        exp,
        m;
    Tuint
        d,
        reserved[12];
};
// выделяет память и возвращает указатель на 'm'
Pint ALLOCX(Tuint len)
{
    if (len == 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    Numx *ptr = (Numx *)operator new((len - 1) * sizeof(Tint) + sizeof(Numx));

    ptr->alen = len;
    ptr->len = 0;
    ptr->sgn = 0;
    ptr->exp = 1;
    ptr->d = 1;

    return &ptr->m;
}
// через макрос container_of получает указатель на структуры и освобождает память
void FREEX(Pint x)
{
    if (x == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    operator delete((void *)container_of(x, Numx, m));
    x = nullptr;
    printf("%p\n", x); // <= выводит '0000000000000000'
}

int main()
{
    Pint x = ALLOCX(1);
    printf("%p\n", x); // <= выводит '000000013F210060'

    FREEX(x);
    printf("%p\n", x); // <= опять '000000013F210060'

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

И так, в чем проблема? Почему в функции FREEX() выводит нули, а сразу после -- нет?

Comment: +1 за слово "укозатель"

Comment: Глупая ошибка x2 :)

Comment: Именно этот момент как раз и иллюстрирует общую бесполезность идеи борьбы с "проблемой с двойным освобождением памяти" путем обнуления указателя. Указателей и вас на одну и ту же область памяти может указывать хоть тысяча. От того, что вы обнулите один из них, остальные не поменяются. И опасность двойного освобождения памяти никуда не исчезнет.

Comment: @AnT Ну хотя бы один и тот же указатель не будет освобожден дважды. А освобождение другого указателя на ту же память уже неясно как избежать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void FREEX(Pint& x)
{
  ...
```

Comment: Мда, довольно глупая ошибка, спасибо

Comment: @complex На здоровье. Успехов!